# How to use fixed values in Spring CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories

Is it possible to add fixed values directly in a `CrudRepository` query method? Like:

```
findAdults(int age > 17);
findAllByBookingDateAndStatus(LocalDate bookingDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1), TypeStatus status = TypeStatus.FAILED);
```

Comment: Just write a query with fixed values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to custom `@Query`'es, you may use default methods.

This is especially useful if default values are calculated in a "complex" way, e.g. `LocalDate.now().minusDays(1)`.

For example:

```
List<Person> findByAgeGreaterThan(int age);

default List<Person> findAdults() {
    return findByAgeGreaterThan(17);
}

---

List<Booking> findAllByBookingDateAndStatus(LocalDate bookingDate, TypeStatus status);

default List<Booking> findAllYesterdaysFailedBookings{
    return findAllByBookingDateAndStatus(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1), TypeStatus.FAILED);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Nice answer, but I found that the default methods in repository are not exposed. Is there any solution?

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee, the default methods in interfaces are actually exposed. Can it be that you are using base type (e.g. `CrudRepository<Person, String>`) instead of your own specific type (e.g. `PersonRepository`)?

Comment: @AlexShesterov My mistake, what I meant to say by "default" is a default method implementation in the interface which internally invokes another method of same interface. For example, my method f1(int arg) takes an integer and its only signature and this is exposed. Now I add another method default f2() { f1(10); } - now this f2 method is not exposed.

Answer (score -3):

For the first one simply use:

```
findByAgeGreaterThan(Integer age);
```

For the second one, just provide the values to match like so:

```
findAllByBookingDateAndStatus(LocalDate bookingDate, TypeStatus status);
```

Spring undestand what you want using the used words "LessThan", "And", "Between" and the like in the name of the queries

Comment: That is not what the question asked for.